# ALM create new Test Run using JSON payload ( REST API)

Tags: java, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "Type": "run",
      "Fields": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "Run_10_07_2019_11_13_53_12345"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "name"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "1"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "test-instance"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "12345"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "testcycl-id"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "56789"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "cycle-id"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "23456"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "test-id"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "hp.qc.test-instance.EXTERNAL"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "subtype-id"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "Passed"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "status"
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "novice"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "owner"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output
{
  "Id": "qccore.general-error",
  "Title": "General Error",
  "ExceptionProperties": null,
  "StackTrace": null
}
500 Internal server error

**I am trying to create a test run using REST API for ALM EndPoint**

```
POST /qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cookie: QCSession=xxx; LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=xxx
```

Can someone please help me out with this issue ?

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request (method, headers, URL) looks correctly.

But your data/JSON must not contain a "multi-entity" document (starting with "entities").

Instead, change it to contain just 1 run entity as follows.

```
{
   "Fields": [
      {
         "Name": "test-id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "843"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "test-name",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "d1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "has-linkage",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "N"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "path",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "cycle-id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "vc-version-number",
         "values": []
      },
      {
         "Name": "draft",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "N"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "host",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "WS-123456"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "state",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "test-config-id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "1234"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "ver-stamp",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "iters-params-values",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "os-build",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "Build 123456"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "os-sp",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "name",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "Run_11-25_9-51-41"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "testcycl-name",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "d1 [1]"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "status",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "Not Completed"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "os-config",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "vc-locked-by",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "bpt-structure",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "cycle",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "execution-date",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "2019-11-25"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "duration",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "4"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "last-modified",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "2019-11-25 09:51:46"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "subtype-id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "hp.qc.run.MANUAL"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "attachment",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "test-description",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "assign-rcyc",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "text-sync",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "owner",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "john_doe"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "pinned-baseline",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "comments",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "iters-sum-status",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "bpta-change-detected",
         "values": []
      },
      {
         "Name": "test-instance",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "cycle-name",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "ts"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "os-name",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "Windows 10"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-07",
         "values": []
      },
      {
         "Name": "environment",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "vc-status",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "execution-time",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "09:51:46"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "bpta-change-awareness",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-01",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-02",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-03",
         "values": []
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-04",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-05",
         "values": [
            {}
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "testcycl-id",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": "1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name": "user-template-06",
         "values": []
      }
   ],
   "Type": "run",
   "children-count": 0
}
```

(Just an example - you probably need to update field names and values to match your particular template).

Comment: Thank you Marteng. One of my friends had helped me out with this issue and its the same solution you have suggested.